# Git ignoring directory not in .gitignore

Tags: git

Nothing happens when I try to add gdb-7.8 to my repository, so I ran check-ignore from the root of the project and it shows:

```
.gitignore:31:*.8   src/.../gdb-7.8/
```

But that line isn't in the .gitignore file:

```
# Object files
*.o
*.ko
*.obj
*.elf

# Libraries
*.lib
*.a

# Shared objects (inc. Windows DLLs)
*.dll
*.so
*.so.*
*.dylib

# Executables
*.exe
*.out
*.app
*.i*86
*.x86_64
*.hex

# Other stuff
*.Plo
*.pp
*.d
*.lo
*.cmd
*.8
*.w
*.img
*.builtin
*.order
*.bin
*.man
*.sub

# Directories
/images
```

There's nothing in .git/info/excludes nor do I have a global .gitignore.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the entire `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Hey, you clearly have a `*.8`  under `other stuff` section of your .gitignore file (31st line, going by check-ignore's output). This is excluding `gdb-7.8` from getting added, as it matches the pattern.

Comment: *facepalm* @face, you're absolutely right! I can't believe I didn't see that!

Comment: @face Life saving comment THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

Git supports having a global excludesfile. It is defined as `core.excludesfile` in your `~/.gitconfig`.

Some software (like [boxen](https://boxen.github.com/)) adds an excludesfile, or overrides a previously existing one, so if you didn't add it yourself, it can come from somewhere else.

You can check whether you have one by running `git config --get core.excludesfile`.

Answer (score 0):

`.gitignore` can exist (almost) anywhere in the tree. Have you tried `find . -name .gitignore` ?

Comment: I think check-ignore is supposed to give you the actual .gitignore file. In this case, it's pointing to the root directory .gitignore. But yes, I also did that to be thorough.